# high resolution image export of powerpoint slide

Tags: images, microsoft-powerpoint, export

I've made a collage in powerpoint and am trying to convert it into an image to send to a printer. Unfortunately, it only converts into a 3072x2304; 96 dpi image. For my print, I will need at least double that resolution.

I've tried the following registry edit: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/827745, but it doesn't seem to change anything (both with save as image as a macro export). The article mentions a maximum resolution only for powerpoint 2003, while I'm working with 2010.

Anybody has an idea on how to fix this? I thought of making side-by-side screenshots, but that will probably take hours.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: An interesting challenge. Question I have is what tools did you use to create the collage.

Comment: Hi Buscar, I just used powerpoint, inserting the images, resizing and fitting them next to each other.

Comment: You are aware that PowerPoint will automatically compress those pictures to preset standard 220 DPI.

Comment: At 96 dpi, your image will print 32x24 inches. Do you need it that big? The "dpi setting" of the image is irrelevant to the printer. Also, if you want to print it, why convert to image first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option might be to export the slide as PDF and print that instead. If that doesn't help, [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org) should allow you to import the PDF and save as [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics).

Comment: At least as of PowerPoint 2019, "Save As > PDF" has advanced options, that allow to preserve the original image resolution. Might be useful in this context.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone runs across this all these years later, note that in PPT 2013 after (I believe it was) SP2 or 3, you can export much higher resolution images, at least via VBA. 10,000 pixels wide is within its range now.